# Alternate Web Browser for S60 Nokia phones

Tags: browser, s60

I have been using a combination of the default web browser and Opera Mini on my Nokia E51 which, although they are not bad, they definitely could be a lot better.

**What other web browsers, preferably free, are out there for s60 that offer compelling features and UIs?**

Comment: Maybe highlight the fact that you're already using Opera by double-bolding it in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's the Opera mobile. I used it on my E65, and enjoyed it a lot. Only problem is the fact it is not free. Yet, it is probably the best browser you can run on a S60 device.

Comment: Not free? From Opera Mobile website: **"Opera Mobile 9.7 beta is free to install and use."** Admittedly it's not libre, only free (as in free beer), and I don't know if they plan to charge for it in the future, but right now it doesn't cost a dime.

Answer (score 2):

[BOLT](http://www.symbian-freeware.com/download-bolt.html)

[Skyfire](http://www.symbian-freeware.com/download-skyfire.html)

[UCWEB](http://www.symbian-freeware.com/download-ucweb.html)

Nokia S60 Web Browser - its open source and u can compile it .

Comment: reason for downvote?

Comment: i was wondering that too...

Answer (score 1):

Opera mobile didn't work properly on my Nokia E90.  I've used [Opera Mini 4.2](http://www.opera.com/mini/download/) for quite a while and am happy with it.  It's free!

Answer (score 1):

Opera Mobile is the one of best web browsers for symbian phones. It also supports javascript in webpages. And it's free too.

It can be downloaded from http://www.opera.com/mobile/

Answer (score 0):

Yet another browser for S60 is [Digia @Web](http://www.digia.com/C2256FEF0043E9C1/0/405001847) though it works on S60 5th edition onwards only.